# facebook application feed dialogue php

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed, facebook-php-sdk

i am trying to generate a feed dialogue through php to post contents o user's wall.
i have taken extended permissions. the variables used have been defined and tested. still the code is not working.
could anyone please tell me whats wrong with the following code:

{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you have issues with your string concatenation:

```
$feed_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
            . "&message=" . $message
            . "&link=" . $linky
            . "&picture=" . $imageurl
            . "&name=" . $name;

if (empty($_REQUEST["post_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $feed_url . "'</script>");
} else {
    echo ("Feed Post Id: " . $_REQUEST["post_id"]);
}
```

Also is it `$linky` or `$link` ?

Comment: there is another issue  i am actually testing it from my local server. the trouble with it is my canvasurl is 127.0.0.1/demo now in case i skip publishing the dialogue. it again comes back to the publish/skip dialogue. how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @gamebit07: How about asking a new question with more details and what page should it redirect to

Comment: hey ifaour please check it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396435/facebook-application-invite-friends-after-posting-on-wall-php-sdk